# NativeScript passing context from app.js directly

Tags: nativescript, binding-context

I have nativescript app where in app.js is set:

```
application.run({ 
    moduleName: "app-root/app-root", 
    context: { 
        param1: "A",
        param2: "B",
        param3: "C",
        param4: "D" 
    } 
});
```

This fires up app-root (Side drawer) but does not pass any params to it. Is this even possible to use this way?
I have push notifications implemented and when notification fires up app, it should send received params to "app-root" page. I've tried with **appSettings** but it's not best (speed) option.
Any suggestions? Thx

Thanks

Comment: I guess `context` is supported only on Page not in root view. Either you may listen for notification from root view Or store data in a module / global object, access the same from root view.

Comment: Hi manoj, I've tried that and it is one of solutions. I've figured out that if app is "killed", notification's data (payload) is not processed and stored in global var / local storage.